# Groups where $G = Z(G) [G, G]$

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition

Is there a name for the groups that can be decomposed as the product of the center by the derived subgroup? Have these groups been studied?

I know that compact connected Lie groups and connected reductive algebraic groups have this property. Which other classes have this decomposition (besides abelian and perfect, of course)?

Comment: The hypothesis implies $[G,G] = [[G,G],[G,G]]$, so $[G,G]$ is perfect, and $G$ is a central product of $[G,G]$ with $Z(G)$.

Comment: So I guess these are precisely the central extensions of a perfect group

Comment: @DietrichBurde - thanks for pointing Luis to my answer!

Comment: @NickyHekster You are welcome! When the next one is asking about these groups I will call them Hekster-groups.

Comment: Haha! It was @mesel who came up with these groups first…